# $T_3$ is quasi isometric to $T_4$

Tags: general-topology, geometry, geometric-group-theory

I have a question which asks me to show that $T_3$ is quasi isometric to $T_4$, that is the three and 4 valence trees.

I know that this means that I have to define a map $f:T_3\rightarrow T_4$ such that we have $\lambda,C,K$ such that for all $x,y\in T_3$ we have:

$\frac{1}{\lambda}d(f(x),f(y))\leq d(x,y)\leq \lambda(f(x),f(y)) +C$ and $\forall x\in T_4$ we have a $y\in T_3$ such that $d(x,f(y))\leq K$

But I am really not sure how I want to be defining my map, never mind showing that it is in fact a quasi isometry

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hint: What is the effect of taking a quotient of $T_3$ by collapsing some edge to a point?

Comment: Will I then get $T_4$ that is if I pick "every third edge" and collapse all my vertexes have valence 4? How do I write this precisely?

Comment: That's the idea. A specific construction could be given by induction on the radius of a ball in $T_3$.

Comment: right ok how would I go about doing that? Would I be looking at the number of collapsed line in a ball of radious $r$?, would I be right in thinking this will then be a quasi-geodesic with $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$ and $C=1$ say?

Comment: That sounds about right, once you've constructed the map.